# How to add new custom submenu under another plugins menu

Tags: wordpress, submenu

There is plugin called Shopp in my WP admin page , this plugin has got top level menu "Shopp" .

**This is the top level menu:**

```
$menus['main'] = add_menu_page('Shopp', 'Shopp', SHOPP_USERLEVEL, 'shopp-orders', array(&$this,'orders'));
```

And I've created some plugin which need to add as submenu under "Shopp" top level menu , so it is adding sub menu ( link .....wp-admin/admin.php?page=ach-faq.php ) but when I am clicking on submenu it shows "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

**Debug result:**

```
Pagenow = admin.php
Parent = shopp-orders
Hookname = shopp_page_ach-faq
Menu = Array
Submenu = Array
Menu nopriv = Array
Submenu nopriv =
Plugin page = ach-faq.php
Registered pages =
```

**My code:**

```
function ach_faq_menu(){
 add_submenu_page('shopp-orders', 'My FAQ Plugin', 'My FAQ Plugin', 8, __FILE__, 'section_1');
}
function section_1(){
 echo 'Text';
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'ach_faq_menu');
```

**How can I fix this ? Please help me !**

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/92474

Answer (score 24):

Menu and submenu pages should be called at the same time, and use the same slugs. For example

```
add_action("admin_menu", "createMyMenus");

function createMyMenus() {
    add_menu_page("My Menu", "My Menu", 0, "my-menu-slug", "myMenuPageFunction");
    add_submenu_page("my-menu-slug", "My Submenu", "My Submenu", 0, "my-submenu-slug", "mySubmenuPageFunction");
}
```

This would result in a top-level menu "My Menu" with a child of "My Submenu".

The invalid permissions error seems to crop up when you use **FILE** for the submenu-slug.

Comment: why is that not in the documentation. It's not obvious that submenu pages need the same slug.

Comment: @TimJoyce They don't need the same slug.  Submenus need the parent slug.  If you want a default sub-menu, which I don't see why you wouldn't, you need to use the same slug.  You can have an action if you were to click on the top level different from all of the sublevel, but that adds confusion.  Standard practice is to have first submenu share the slug and its action will override the action of the parent.

Comment: I followed this article to create a sub-menu under the main menu of an active plugin, so simple.

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/administration-menus/sub-menus/

Answer (score 4):

To add it on one of the plugin's parent menu, use add_submenu_page() and set the priority of your add_action() to lower i.e, above 10.

Then in add_submenu_page(), replace 'plugin-parent-menu-slug' with the slug of the parent menu where you want it to add. Example, you want to add it under an admin page with a slug /wp-admin/admin.php?page=**plugin-parent-menu-slug**.

```
// set priority to lower i.e. greater than 10
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu', 20 );

function my_admin_menu() {
    add_submenu_page( 'plugin-parent-menu-slug', 'New Menu', 'New Menu', 'manage_options', 'my-admin-slug', 'my_admin_page' );
}

function my_admin_page(){
    echo "My Admin Page";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add submenu to existing custom menu (added by other plugin) with little bit tricky

you can create menu and then remove the menu itself after you add submenu with same slug and callback.

Please try this code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_shopp_submenu' );
function add_shopp_submenu(){
    add_menu_page( __('New Menu', 'your-plugin-text-domain'), __('New Menu', 'your-plugin-text-domain'), 'read', 'ach-faq', 'your_menu_callback');
    add_submenu_page( 'shopp-orders', __('New Menu', 'your-plugin-text-domain'), __('New Menu', 'your-plugin-text-domain'), 'read', 'ach-faq', 'your_menu_callback' );
    remove_menu_page('ach-faq');
}

function your_menu_callback(){
    echo "string";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Altari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298503/altari) stated:

> Menu and submenu pages should be called at the same time

**SAME TIME** - add_submenu_page must be called from same function as add_menu_page, the function in original plugin. You **can not** "hack" into another plugins menu from outside of it.

Comment: note that to use add_submenu_page in separate function, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/92474 helped me and worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can by adding the plugin folder name and the home page of the plugin.
For example I hooked to the Newsletter plugin by:

```
<?php 

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_newsletter_extra_page');

function add_newsletter_extra_page(){
    add_submenu_page( 
        'newsletter/intro.php', 
        'Newsletter', 
        'Subscribers Plus', 
        1, //$capability, 
        'subscribers-plus',
        'newsletter_list_addon' );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*create any function name*/
function process_post() {

 add_menu_page(__('nLr','menu-test'), __('My Plugin','menu-test'), 'manage_options','myplugin', 'myplguin_admin_page', 'dashicons-tickets', 6 );

add_submenu_page('myplugin', __('My Plugin Edit', 'menu-test'), __('My Plugin Edit', 'menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'myplugin_edit', 'myplugin_edit');

 }
/*create callback function for main menu*/

function myplguin_admin_page(){
    echo"welcom to my plugin menu";

}

/* create callback function for submenu */

function myplugin_edit(){
    echo"welcome to submenu";
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'process_post' );
?>
```

Answer (score -6):

Go to Appearance -> Menus
Then Create Menu under Custom Links, then a new menu created in right side. Now you can just drag that and put under which top level menu you want.

Comment: the question is about the administration menu, not the front-end ones.