# How to create Wordpress <form> with custom variables on blank page?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to create a form with Wordpress on blank page.
I have some variables for the form that should be configured in the admin panel.
So my question is:

1. How can i create A custom form (not with a plugin) and display it to the user?
2. how can i store variables in the admin panel, and grab them as the form loads?

Comment: you can create a template in theme yourtemplate.php file .. then create a page from admin which will be blank and select that template .. inside this page you can code the form in youtemplate.php and insert data in table by creating a new table and put insert query there.

Comment: for backend you can use functions.php file and use wordpress' actions and filters to create submenu or menu and can show the results without creating  a plugin.

Comment: check this may help you for admin side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240460/how-to-add-new-custom-submenu-under-another-plugins-menu

Comment: you can create shortcode